# React frontend not showing after deploying MERN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I have just successfully deployed an MVP MERN application to Heroku. However, My React frontend is not showing. I am just getting a blank screen. I am following the deployment tutorial here: https://dev.to/hawacodes/deploying-a-mern-app-with-heroku-3km7

I know my express server is working fine, since my Heroku app displays the JSON returned from the server whenever the server starts.

My `scripts` section in `package.json` looks like this

```json
"scripts": {
    "build-sample-front": "cd sample-front && npm run build",
    "install-sample-front": "cd sample-front && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-sample-front && npm run build-sample-front",
    "server": "node app.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run start --prefix sample-front\"",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run start --prefix sample-front\""
  }
```

where `sample-front` is the directory where my react app is located.

My dependencies in `package.json` looks like this,

```json
"dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

My `app.js` looks like this,

```js
import {
    port,
    host, 
    setup,
    useEJS,
    useCORS,
    mountRouter,
    initSessions,
    connectSessions,
    accessRequestBody, 
} from './scripts/server.js';
import { deckRouter } from './routes/deck.js';
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const sessionDB = connectSessions();
const app = setup();
useEJS(app);
useCORS(app);
initSessions(app);
accessRequestBody(app);

mountRouter(app,'/deck',deckRouter);
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    let deckName = '';
    let deckList = 'Pot of Greed 3\nGraceful Charity 3\nChange of Heart 3';
    if (req.session.deckName) {
        deckName = req.session.deckName;
    }
    if (req.session.deckList) {
        deckList = req.session.deckList;
        deckList = deckList.reduce((deckListStr,card) => { return deckListStr + card + '\n'; },'');
    }
    res.json({ status: 200,deckName: deckName,deckList: deckList });
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log('attempting to server static files');
    const __dirname = path.resolve();
    app.use(express.static('sample-front/build'));
    app.get('*',(req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'sample-front','build','index.html'));
    });
}

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://${host}:${port}`)
});
```

the `useCORS` function is defined as,

```js
export function useCORS(server) {
    // Specify the origin of the react app frontend
    server.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
}
```

My `Procfile` looks like this,

```
web: node app.js
```

My project directory structure is as follows (I leave out directory contents, except for app.js, for brevity),

```
db/
node_modules/
routes/
sample-front/
    node_modules/
    public/
    src/
scripts/
app.js
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your still using local address (localhost) instead of the actual endpoint. is this might be your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by:

1. Adding a proxy to the React app `package.json` where `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"`
2. Then I remove the `/` route from my `app.js` replacing it with `/preload` ensuring that my static react files in build get loaded.